# Sum of square of numbers after range increment

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There are 1 to n numbers. I will save summation of square of n numbers,
**i=1 to n, Σ = (arr[i]*arr[i])**.
Then, there is an increment to all numbers 1 to n. The increment is same to all numbers.
Is there any formula to calculate the total sum in O(1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_i$, for $1 \le i \le n$, be each the original $n$ numbers, and let $a$ be the increment being added to each of them. The new sum is then

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
S & = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}(x_i + a)^2 \\
& = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}(x_i^2 + 2ax_i + a^2) \\
& = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_i^2 + \sum_{i = 1}^{n}2ax_i + \sum_{i = 1}^{n}a^2 \\
& = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_i^2 + 2a\sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_i + na^2
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Thus, if you also calculate and save the summation of the original $n$ numbers themselves, you can then use \eqref{eq1A} to get the new summation value within basically a small constant computer time, i.e., $O(1)$.